# Virtualbox Client hangs (mouse) in fullscreen only

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, fullscreen

Host machine: Debian 12.0 (x86_64)
Guest machine: Linux Mint 21.1 (x86_64)
VirtualBox version: 7.0.10
Guest Additions installed (7.0.10)
Extension Pack installed (7.0.10)

Everything works fine using the guest in windowed mode.
After enabling full screen the client does not react to mouse clicks anymore and I need to shut down using the keyboard.
I installed everything in standard mode and did not change my settings in the VM manager.
I tried the other graphic controllers and turned off 3D graphic acelleration too without success.
A weird problem ...

Comment: Seems strange. Consider a full uninstall of VBOX, restart and complete reinstall.  See if the mouse works. Consider a replacement mouse

Answer (score 0):

I found out that on the host I need to login with "Gnome under X.org".
This helped me to find the problem:

> https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=105041